# how to change centura theme at runtime

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

How to change application theme at run time of an application developed in Team developer. I have already tried Build Settings - General settings, but  there I didn't find any option for changing theme at run time.

Comment: FYI 'Centura' used to be the generic term used for Gupta SQLWindows / TeamDeveloper and associated toolset. Actually, Centura only released one version of the toolset - v1.5. The toolset is now owned and developed by OpenText ( commonly referred to as Gupta ) and the latest release is v7.1 - which is native 64bit , UNICODE and .Net enabled. Theme concept was introduced in Gupta TeamDeveloper v5.0. Go here to see the OpenText Gupta Product Overview :  https://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases/opentext-gupta-team-developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change theme programatically at run time using  the below mentioned Sal functions,

SalThemeSet

bOk = SalThemeSet( ThemeId) 
Where parameter ThemeId - numeric value that specifies theme.

Few Supported Theme values are listed below,

0 - THEME_Default

1 - THEME_Office2000

2 - THEME_OfficeXP

3 - THEME_Office2003

4 - THEME_Office2003NoThemes

5 - THEME_Studio2005

6 - THEME_Studio2008

7 - THEME_NativeXP

8 - THEME_Office2007_R1

9 - THEME_Office2007_R2_LunaBlue

10 - THEME_Office2007_R2_Obsidian

11 - THEME_Office2007_R2_Silver

12 - THEME_Office2007_R3_LunaBlue

13 - THEME_Office2007_R3_Obsidian

14 - THEME_Office2007_R3_Silver

15 - THEME_Office2010_R1

16 - THEME_Office2010_R2_Blue

17 - THEME_Office2010_R2_Silver

18 - THEME_Office2010_R2_Black

Also you can try SalThemeGet ( ) function for retrieving theme at run time.
The function will return numeric theme value.
Let me know if you have any more questions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware there is a recent registered issue concerning *some* Themes showing heavy flickering on forms when activated / deactivated when switching focus between different MDI child windows containing many controls.

THEME_Office2013 shows the flickering, while TD native XP theme does not.

See [TD-23978: Most Themes show heavy flickering on forms when activated / deactivated](http://forum.tdcommunity.net/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=45860&sid=c9117ec4ded3fe54bb635137d23f68c3#p153045)